# how to do multi search in a datagridview using multi different textboxes

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I made small that will do the following

1. load an excel file into `datagridview`
2. filter data within the `datagridview` using multiple `textbox` example 
   National_ID and middle name and last name on the `Textbox_TextChanged` event as shown.

my problem is that this filtering when enter data in text `TB_National_ID`
it will filter data fine but when I want to filter data based on two textbox
`TB_National_ID` and `TB_FName` or more results are not correct how to solve this issue 
so I can filter based on one or two or three or more `textboxs`

```
        private void TB_National_ID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = string.Format("convert(ID,'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%' ", TB_National_ID.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        //Re-calculate record counts
        Rec_Count.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }

    private void TB_FName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = "Name LIKE '%" + TB_FName.Text + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        //Re-calculate record counts
        Rec_Count.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```

**update**

I came out with that solution as below but kindly if there is faster way because I am filtering around `10,000` rows

I am calling this method on each `TextChanged` event

```
    public void DataFilter()
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = string.Format("convert(ID,'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%' and Name LIKE '%{1}%' ", TB_National_ID.Text, TB_Full_Name.Text);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        //Re-calculate record counts
        Rec_Count.Text = dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply “filter” the EXISTING `BindingSource` instead of creating a new one every time the text is changed? The `BindingSource` would be a global variable.

Comment: @JohnG nice suggestion I give it try but I get error messeage `BindingSource cannot be its own data source. Do not set the DataSource and DataMember properties to values that refer back to BindingSource`  I searched and found that is because BindingSource within another thread

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing where your error is in the code, speculation is about all that anyone can offer. One point I would recommend you look for is the re-setting of the `DataSource` AFTER you have set the filter. Example: in the last snippet of posted code: `DataFilter` method… re-creating a new `BindingSource` is un-necessary. Make your `BindingSource` a global variable and simply set ITS filter. The second issue is AFTER you set the filter for the `BindingSource` the code reassigns the `DatagridViews` `DataSource` to the `BindingSource`… as before this is un-necessary.

Make a global `DataTable`, fill it with your Excel data, then use it as a `DataSource` to the `BindingSource`. You can then use this `BindingSource` as a `DataSource` to the `DataGridView`. NOTE: you will only need to do this ONCE. After the grids data source has been set, applying a “filter” to the `BindingSource` should automatically update the `DataGridView` to reflect this filter. There is no need to reassign the grids `DataSource`. The `DataFilter` method should be ONE line of code: `bs.Filter = Your filter string….`

Below is an example of what I described above. I ran it with over 13,000+ rows of data and it did not appear too sluggish. Obviously, with more data the filter delays may not be acceptable. The code starts with a winform that contains a `DataGridView` to store the excel files and two (2) `TextBoxes` used to filter the `DataGridView` based on what the user types into the text boxes.

There are four (4) global variables:

A `string` `DefaultDirectory` that stores the path to the Excel files.

A `string[]` `ExcelFilePaths` that contains the string paths for all the Excel files in the `DefaultDirectory`.

A `DataTable` `BindingSourceDataTable`  this `DataTable` contains all the combined worksheets stacked one on top of the other with a blank row between each worksheet.

Finally a `BindingSource` `GridBindingSource` whose `DataSource` is the previous `DataTable`. It is used as a `DataSource` to the `DataGridView` and is also used as the target to filter data.

Methods:
`ImportExcel(string FilePath)`… takes a string path to an Excel workbook and returns a `DataTable` that contains the data from the worksheet named “Sheet1” if found. Otherwise, it returns null, indicating that the worksheet named “Sheet1” was not found.

`GetDataFromExcel()` returns a single `DataTable` that contains data from all the worksheets named “Sheet1” from all the workbooks in the `DefaultDirectory`. This method uses the `DataTable.Merge` property to merge the individual worksheet `DataTables` (`tempTable`) to form the final large `DataTable` `mergedTables`. I presume that the worksheets all have an identical column schema; otherwise, the sheets may not stack as expected. If the column schemas are identical, then the sheets should stack one on top of the other.

Finaly, `GetFilterStringFromTextBoxes()` returns a filter string from the two text boxes. This method is called each time the text changes in one of the text boxes. This filter string will filter the data as the user types. To clear any filter the user simply needs to clear the text boxes.

Obviously, you will want to adjust the filter string to match the column names in your data table etc..

Hope this helps.

```
string DefaultDirectory = @"D:\Test\ExcelFiles\";
string[] ExcelFilePaths;
DataTable BindingSourceDataTable = new DataTable();
BindingSource GridBindingSource = new BindingSource();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  BindingSourceDataTable = GetDataFromExcel();
  GridBindingSource.DataSource = BindingSourceDataTable;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridBindingSource;
}

public DataTable GetDataFromExcel() {
  ExcelFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(DefaultDirectory, "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
  DataTable mergedTables = new DataTable();
  string FilePath;
  for (int i = 0; i < ExcelFilePaths.Length; i++) {
    FilePath = ExcelFilePaths[i];
    DataTable tempTable = ImportExcel(FilePath);
    if (tempTable != null) {  // <- ignore workbook files missing the worksheet named 'Sheet1'
      if (i < ExcelFilePaths.Length - 1) { // <- if its the last worksheet do not add the extra row 
        tempTable.Rows.Add();
      }
      mergedTables.Merge(tempTable);
    }
  }
  return mergedTables;
}

public DataTable ImportExcel(string FilePath) {
  string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";";
  using (OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr)) {
    try {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", Conn);
      DA.Fill(dt);
      return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      // ignore workbook files missing the worksheet named 'Sheet1'
      //MessageBox.Show("No worksheet named 'Sheet1' - Error: " + e.Message);
      return null;
    }
  }
}

private void tbFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridBindingSource.Filter = GetFilterStringFromTextBoxes();
}

private void tbLastName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridBindingSource.Filter = GetFilterStringFromTextBoxes();
}

private string GetFilterStringFromTextBoxes() {
  return string.Format("Customer_Firstname LIKE '%{0}%' and Customer_Lastname LIKE '%{1}%' ", tbFirstName.Text, tbLastName.Text);
}
```